# Comparing two arrays in an OCR

Tags: java

I am making a primitive OCR project. I wrote a method that compares an image matrix to number matrices and "scores" them, with the highest number matrix being the best match. Here's my method:

```
public double compareMatrices(int[][] num, int[][] img) {
    int nNumRows = num.length;
    int nNumCols = num[0].length;
    int nImgRows = img.length;
    int nImgCols = img[0].length;

    double highest = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < nImgRows - nNumRows + 1; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < nImgCols - nNumCols + 1; col++) {
            double score = 0;
            for 
            (int row_offset = 0; row_offset < nNumRows; row_offset++) {
                for (int col_offset = 0; 
                        col_offset < nNumCols; col_offset++) {
                    int imgRowIndex = row + row_offset;
                    int imgColIndex = col + col_offset;
                    int numV = num[row_offset][col_offset];
                    int imgV = img[imgRowIndex][imgColIndex];

                    if ((imgV == 1) && (numV == 1)) {
                        score +=1;
                    } else if ((numV == 1) & (imgV == 0)) {
                        score -= 0.25;
                    } else if ((numV == 0) && (imgV == 0)) {
                        score += 0.25;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (score > highest) {
                highest = score;
            }
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Now I am trying to write a method that determines which of the number matrices is the best match by comparing the scores from the `compareMatrices` method.

What I have is this, where the `imgd0` is a test image (or do I even need to specify an image? Can I just say there will be an image matrix to be compared to?):

```
public String FindBestMatch() { 
    numFiles.getMatrix("zero");
    compareMatrices(int[][] zero, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("one");
    compareMatrices(int[][] one, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("two");
    compareMatrices(int[][] two, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("three");
    compareMatrices(int[][] three, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("four");
    compareMatrices(int[][] four, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("five");
    compareMatrices(int[][] five, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("six");
    compareMatrices(int[][] six, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("seven");
    compareMatrices(int[][] seven, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("eight");
    compareMatrices(int[][] eight, imgd0);
    numFiles.getMatrix("nine");
    compareMatrices(int[][] nine, imgd0);
```

Where numFiles.getMatrix is a method that comes from:

```
public class NumFiles {

    private int[][] one = makeMatrix("one.txt");
    private int[][] two= makeMatrix("two.txt");
    private int[][] three= makeMatrix("three.txt");
    private int[][] four= makeMatrix("four.txt");
    private int[][] five= makeMatrix("five.txt");
    private int[][] six= makeMatrix("six.txt");
    private int[][] seven= makeMatrix("seven.txt");
    private int[][] eight= makeMatrix("eight.txt");
    private int[][] nine= makeMatrix("nine.txt");
    private int[][] zero= makeMatrix("zero.txt");

    public NumFiles() {
    }

    public int[][] getMatrix(String num){
        if (num == "one") {
            return one;
        }
        else if (num == "two"){
            return two;
        }
        else if (num == "three"){
            return three;
        }
        else if (num == "four") {
            return four;
        }
        else if (num == "five") {
            return five;
        }
        else if (num == "six") {
            return six;
        }
        else if (num == "seven"){
            return seven;
        }
        else if (num == "eight"){
            return eight;
        }
        else if (num == "nine") {
            return nine;
        }
        else if (num == "zero") {
            return zero;
        }
        else {
            int [][] k = {{-1},{-1}};
            return k;
        }
    }
```

So what I'm asking is for my `FindBestMatch` method, is there a better way to write it than to go through every single number matrix, running `compareMatrices` every single time against one single test image? Thanks!

Comment: You use the equals method to compare Strings, not the ==.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc == works fine for what I'm trying to do. I'm really just having trouble with the `FindBestMatch` method

Comment: Where exactly is your issue? You may also have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to improve the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question; if you're asking whether you need to type it all out, then the answer is no; you create a class that describes your image

```
class Image {String name; int[][] pixels;}
```

Then you keep a list of your images

```
List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can load them from a file or directory (code omitted), and you can iterate over the list in a very elegant way with streams and reduce(), but I'm too sleepy to actually type it out.